# What's the role of the diode in this debouncing circuit?

Tags: switch-debouncing

I am testing Ganssles debouncing circuit described [here](http://ohm.bu.edu/%7Epbohn/__Engineering_Reference/debouncing.pdf):

[image]

After running some tests, it seems that the diode is redundant for my circuit to function as intended (where R1 & R2 = 20 kΩ, C = 1 μF). Even though I understand the function of bypassing R2 when charging the capacitor, I don't understand Ganssle description of the purpose of the diode (page 13):

> The diode is an optional part needed only when the math goes haywire. It’s possible, with
> the wrong sort of gate where the hysteresis voltages assume other values, for the formulas
> to pop out a value for R1 + R2 which is less than that of R2 . In this case the diode forms a
> short cut that removes R2 from the charging circuit. All of the charge flows through R1.

I can't unpack this description. Could someone please break this down for me like I'm five?

Comment: Well the original source ought to explain this better or it is not a good source to use in your designs. That's kind of the whole point of writing a blog @Jack Ganssle...

Comment: @Lundin Can you explain it?

Comment: Simply put: C charges through R1 and discharges through R2.

Comment: @Velvel Yes. It's the quote I'm asking about.

Comment: The paper discusses the functions to charge and discharge the capacitor. It's up to you to decide what the charge and discharge timings have to be. When discharging only \$R_2\$ comes into play (\$R_{discharge}=R_2\$). For charging and without diode \$R_{charge}=R_1+R_2\$. If your calculated \$R_{charge}\$ is less than \$R_2\$, then you'll need the diode in able to obtain \$R_{charge}=R_1\$.

Comment: @Velvel And the "It’s possible, with the wrong sort of gate where the hysteresis voltages assume other values, for the formulas to pop out a value for R1 + R2 which is less than that of R2" quote?

Comment: The hardware gate determines the thresholds \$V_{th,high}\$ and \$V_{th,low}\$, which also factor into the equations. You need to check the datasheet of your specific hardware.

Comment: This circuit was designed decades before the linked book wrote about it.

Answer (score 2):

The diode allows you to *independently* select the charge and discharge time constants. Without it, you  have R1+R2 and R2 respectively.

Depending on what numbers you come up with for your times it may help.

I didn't read much of what you linked, but I would suggest some caution in depending on tests, as switch bounce can change significantly during the life, and typically for the worse. Switch datasheet values (plus a bit of safety margin) are better, when available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the switch has no datasheets for electrical properties. The tests I'm doing is my best bet to determine safety margins.

Answer (score 1):

As said already, the diode allows to select both charging and discharging resistances independently.

But it means the values are selected based on what the Schmitt trigger gate thresholds are, and you still have to count the effect of the diode voltage drop.

The diode will only help up to a point when current is high enough to have otherwise higher voltage drop over R2 than the diode voltage drop, which is about 0.7V. Over 20k resistor, that's 35 microamps. So in theory, the diode is useful up to point when there's 0.7V over both R1 and R2, so capacitor is charged to 3.3V at rate of 20k and after that at rate of 40k to 5V.

It is possible that you want very different charging and discharging currents based on your switch bounce behaviour, capacitor value, and input buffer.

For example you say you use 20k resistors and 1uF capacitor. So without diode, cap discharges faster through 20k, but charges via total of 40k, which is slower.

That might be fine for CMOS buffer input such as 74HC14.

But for another type of buffer such as 7414, the 20k resistors are so high in resistance that pushing the button will have no effect on the buffer input, due to buffer input impedance. It will source and sink current. The R2 needs to be somewhere near 500 ohms or so, and R1 needs to be somewhere near 4700 ohms.

The resistors also need to be selected so that the peak current when discharging the capacitor does not exceed the safe current limit for the pushbutton, and also so that when kept pushed there will be a minimum wetting current to help making a reliable contact.